# How to eliminate "Avoid Large Layout Shifts" for the below code?

Tags: html, css, layout, pagespeed

In lighthouse it shows avoid large layout shift for the following element:

```
<div id="HomeNewsEventsWrapper" class="section fixedheight1 introduction">
```

It shows avoid large layout shift even after setting width and height

```
<div id="HomeNewsEventsWrapper" class="section fixedheight1 introduction" style="width:375px;height:639px;">
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

A shifted element is often the victim of another element above it being inserted or changing size. So you need to figure out why this element shifted and fix *that* element from causing the shift to *this* element.

We’re looking at ways to report the probable cause more in Lighthouse but for now we just list the element shifted (as that’s how CLS is measured).